# Retrofit 2: Use cached response then network response

Tags: java, android, caching, networking, retrofit

I don't know if it's possible at all without building a wrapper around Retrofit.
I would like my request to go trough the callback 2 times, once with the cached / disk response, and once from the network (if available).

For the moment I use a custom okHttpClient with a custom Interceptor as follow:

```java
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(new Cache()).build();
```

And here is the Cache interceptor

```java
public class Cache implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            if (Network.isConnected()) {
                Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                byte[] buffer = response.body().bytes();
                NetworkCache.cacheResponse(request, buffer);
                return new Response.Builder()
                        .code(response.code())
                        .request(request)
                        .protocol(response.protocol())
                        .headers(response.headers())
                        .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse(RestClient.MEDIA_TYPE), buffer))
                        .build();
            } else {
                Response cachedResponse = NetworkCache.getResponse(request);
                if (cachedResponse != null) {
                    return cachedResponse;
                }
            }
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

It works, but my cached response are only triggered if the device is offline (as excepted by this code). Now I would like to have a chance to respond two times, even if the device is online, to respond with the cached response first, and then with the networked one if available.

Is that possible with an Interceptor?